# Equivalent condition for interpolation polynomial

Tags: polynomials, determinant, interpolation

> Let $(x_1,y_1),...,(x_n,y_n)\in \mathbb{R}^2  $, where $x_i\neq x_j$ if $i\neq j$. Let  $p$ be a polynomial such that 
>   $$\det\begin{pmatrix} 
> p(x)& 1 & x & x^2 &\dots & x^n \\
> y_0 & 1 & x_0 & x_0^2 &\dots &x_0^n \\
> y_1 & 1 & x_1 & x_1^2 &\dots &x_1^n \\
> \vdots & & & & & \vdots \\
> y_n & 1 & x_n & x_n^2 &\dots & x_n^n 
> \end{pmatrix}=0. $$
>   Then $p(x_k)=y_k ,\forall k=1,...,n$.

My ideas: We should compute the determinant using Laplace's formula, although I can't see a nice pattern to do a proof by induction or to conclude the proposition.

Thanks for the help

bests

bjn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint.** Put $x=x_0$ and subtract the second row from the first row. The determinant is then equal to
$$
\det\pmatrix{p(x_0)-y_0&0_{1\times(n+1)}\\ \ast&V}=(p(x_0)-y_0)\det(V),
$$
where $V$ is a [Vandermonde matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix). In order that this is zero, ...